# Error using Insertion Sort algorithm - array is not sorted exactly.

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort, insertion-sort

Here is some working code that implements a modified version of the Quicksort algorithm that uses Insertion Sort for array size `n > 8`. My test array isn't sorting exactly right, and I think it must be with my implementation of `Insertionsort` and `Insert`.

The general form of the recursive `Insertionsort` algorithm is:

```
void Insertionsort(int S[], int n)
{
        if(n>1)
                Insertionsort(S,n-1);
        Insert(S,n-1);

}

void Insert(int *S, int k)
{
        int key = S[k];
        int j = k-1;
        while(j>=0 && S[j] > key)
        {
                S[j+1] = S[j];
                j--;
        }

        S[j+1] = key;
}
```

Here is my complete working code that does not sort quite exactly right:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int comparisons = 0;            
int compare_qs_m3_ins[12];  


// Function prototypes
int partition(int *S,int l, int u);                                          
void exchange(int list[], int p, int q);
void Insert(int S[], int k);                                                
void Insertionsort(int S[], int low, int hi);                           
void Quicksort_Insert_M3(int S[], int n, int p, int r);       



int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    // Declare all arrays used for testing
    int S1_500[500];
    int S2_500[500];
    int S3_500[500];


    int S1_300[300];
    int S2_300[300];
    int S3_300[300];

    int S1_100[100];
    int S2_100[100];
    int S3_100[100];

    int S1_8[8];
    int S2_8[8];
    int S3_8[8];




    // Fill arrays with random integers
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        S1_500[i] = rand()%1000;
        S2_500[i] = rand()%1000;
        S3_500[i] = rand()%1000;
    }


    for(int i=0; i<300; i++)
    {
        S1_300[i] = rand()%1000;
        S2_300[i] = rand()%1000;
        S3_300[i] = rand()%1000;
    }


    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        S1_100[i] = rand()%500;
        S2_100[i] = rand()%500;
        S3_100[i] = rand()%500;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        S1_8[i] = rand()%100;
        S2_8[i] = rand()%100;
        S3_8[i] = rand()%100;
    }

    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S1_500,500,0,499);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[0] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S2_500,500,0,499);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[1] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S3_500,500,0,499);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[2] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S1_300,300,0,299);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[3] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S2_300,300,0,299);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[4] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S3_300,300,0,299);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[5] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S1_100,100,0,99);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[6] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S2_100,100,0,99);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[7] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S3_100,100,0,99);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[8] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S1_8,8,0,7);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[9] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S2_8,8,0,7);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[10] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;
    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S3_8,8,0,7);
    compare_qs_m3_ins[11] = comparisons;
    comparisons = 0;

    //for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        //cout << compare_qs_m3_ins[i] << endl;



    for(int i=0;i<499;i++)
        cout << S1_500[i] << endl;





}



int partition(int *S,int l, int u)
{
    int x = S[l];
    int j = l;
    for(int i=l+1; i<=u; i++)
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(S[i] < x)
        {   
            j++;
            swap(S[i],S[j]);
        }

    }
    int p = j;
    swap(S[l],S[p]);
    return p;
}

void swap(int &val1, int &val2)
{
    int temp = val1;
    val1 = val2;
    val2 = temp;
}


void exchange(int list[], int p, int q)
{
    int temp = list[p];
    list[p] = list[q];
    list[q] = temp;
}


int Sort3(int list[], int p, int r)
{
    int median = (p + r) / 2;
    comparisons++;
    if(list[p] <= list[median])
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[median]>list[r])
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(list[p]<list[r])
            {
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[r];
                list[r] = list[median];
                list[median] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                exchange(list,median,r);
            }
        }
        else
            ;

    }
    else
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[p] > list[r])
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(list[median] < list[r])
            {
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[median];
                list[median] = list[r];
                list[r] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                exchange(list,p,r);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exchange(list,p,median);
        }

    }


    return list[r];
}


void Insert(int *S, int k)
{
    int key = S[k];
    int j = k-1;
    while(j>=0 && S[j] > key)
    {
        S[j+1] = S[j];
        j--;
        comparisons++;
    }
    comparisons++;
    S[j+1] = key;
}


void Insertionsort(int S[], int low, int hi)
{
    if((hi-low)+1>1)
        Insertionsort(S,low+1,hi);
    Insert(S,hi-low);

}


void Quicksort_Insert_M3(int S[], int n, int low, int hi)
{
    if((hi-low)<=8)
        Insertionsort(S,low,hi);
    else 
    {
        if(low < hi)
        {
            if((low+1) == hi)
            {
                comparisons++;
                if(S[low] > S[hi])
                    swap(S[low],S[hi]);
            }
            else
            {
                Sort3(S,low,hi);
                if((low+2)<hi)
                {
                    swap(S[low+1],S[(low+hi)/2]);
                    int q = partition(S, low+1, hi-1);
                    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S, n, low, q-1);
                    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S, n, q+1, hi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Works every time! (if you know what should happen at any given line)

Comment: Actually, I ran a small test case and the `Insertionsort` function works. It is actually my implementation of the `Quicksort_Insert_M3` that doesn't - not sure where though.

Comment: I suggest replacing your while loop in Insert with a for loop ... because you are doing a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function supposed to sort three array elements in ascending order doesn't:

```
int Sort3(int list[], int p, int r)
{
```

called only for `p + 2 <= r`, so

```
    int median = (p + r) / 2;
```

`p < median < r` here. Let `a = list[p]`, `b = list[median]` and `c = list[r]`.

```
    comparisons++;
    if(list[p] <= list[median])
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[median]>list[r])
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(list[p]<list[r])
            {
```

So here we have `a <= b`, `c < b` and `a < c`, together `a < c < b`

```
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[r];
                list[r] = list[median];
                list[median] = temp;
```

but you place them in order `c, a, b`. Probably you intended to use `if (list[r] < list[p])` there.

```
            }
            else
```

`c <= a <= b`

```
            {
                exchange(list,median,r);
```

so that arranges them in order `a, c, b`.

```
            }
        }
        else
            ;

    }
    else
```

Here, `b < a`.

```
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[p] > list[r])
        {
```

`c < a`

```
            comparisons++;
            if(list[median] < list[r])
            {
```

Then `b < c < a`

```
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[median];
                list[median] = list[r];
                list[r] = temp;
```

Yup, that's correct.

```
            }
            else
```

`c <= b < a`

```
            {
                exchange(list,p,r);
            }
```

Okedoke.

```
        }
        else
        {
```

`b < a <= c`

```
            exchange(list,p,median);
```

Okay.

```
        }

    }


    return list[r];
}
```

Why does this function return anything? You don't use the return value anyway.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that error - that is correct. Also, I changed it to a `void` function - no need to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

"The general form of the recursive Insertionsort algorithm is" - if you need to have a head-recursive algorithm, yes, otherwise a better version is:

```
void Insertionsort(int S[], int i, int n)
{
    Insert(S, i, n);
    if(i < n)
        Insertionsort(S, i+1, n);
}
```

which is much more understandable. Also, you might as well have put the body of Insert into Insertionsort.

I'm not going to try and figure out your overly complicated version of quicksort. A decent quicksort is around 20 lines or less (like this - www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) (and add another 10 or less for insertion sort). I suggest getting a better understanding by looking at another implementation and rewriting yours.

I believe this could've been asked as an extension of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489895).